# Find the gcd of Gaussian Integers

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find the greatest common divisor in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ of $11+7i$ and $18-i$.

Actually, I don't know why I have to calculate $b\bar{a}=191-137i$, and $a\bar{a}=170$,

and this $191-137i = 170(?)+(21+33i), ?=1-i$.

Then, I can get $18-i=(11+7i)(1-i)+3i$.

Following $11+7i=(3i)(2-3i)+2+i$, $3i=(2+i)(1+i)-1$, $(2+i)=(-1)(-2-i)$

I get (2+i) is the g.c.d. (Is it really right?)

Comment: The title should be the gcd of Gaussian Integers.

Comment: @MichaelBurr, Thanks

Comment: Frankly, what you wrote is almost unintelligible...

Comment: @A.P., I was trying to figure out the g.c.d.. But I don't know the reason behind for the steps I knew.

Comment: Do you know what is the *norm* of an element in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$?

Comment: @A.P. Is it $\surd{(a^{2}+b^{2})}$ ?

Comment: Almost: it is the square of that.

Comment: But why should we use $norm$ here?

Comment: @user131605 I added a couple simple ways to do it in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that if $N(a+ib) = a^2+b^2$ and $d,x \in \Bbb{Z}[i]$, then $d \mid x$ implies $N(d) \mid N(x)$. Now, an easy computation shows that
$$
\begin{align}
N(11 + 7i) &= 170 = 2 \cdot 5 \cdot 17 \\
N(18 - i) &= 325 = 5^2 \cdot 13
\end{align}
$$
hence $d = \gcd(11 + 7i,18 - i)$ is either an element of norm $5$ or a unit, because it can be proved that $N(u) = 1$ iff $u$ is invertible. Now, the only solutions in $\Bbb{Z}^2$ of
$$
a^2 + b^2 = 5
$$
are $(\pm 1, \pm 2)$ and $(\pm 2, \pm 1)$, so the only elements of norm $5$ in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ are $\pm 1 \pm 2i$ and $\pm 2 \pm i$. Since the $d$ is unique up to multiplication by a unit, it is enough to check if any of these divides both $11 + 7i$ and $18 - i$.

Note that the only solutions in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ of
$$
N(a + bi) = a^2 + b^2 = 1
$$
are $\pm 1, \pm i$, so these are the only units. In particular, this means that it is enough to check if
$$
d = 1 + 2i \quad \text{or} \quad d = 1 - 2i
$$
because these are not associated and every element of norm $5$ is associated to one of these (note that $2 + i = i(1 - 2i))$. Further, we can observe that only one of these can divide, say, $11 + 7i$, because otherwise $(1 + 2i)(1 - 2i) = 1 + 4 = 5$ would divide it, too (and this is absurd). The same holds for $18 - i$.

Finally, observe that
$$
(1 + 2i)(a + bi) = a - 2b + (2a + b)i
$$
hence $(1 + 2i) \mid x + yi$ in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ if and only if there are $a,b \in \Bbb{Z}$ such that
$$
\begin{cases}
x = a - 2b \\
y = 2a + b
\end{cases}
$$
This system gives $(1 + 2i)(5 - 3i) = 11 + 7i$ (so, in particular, your solution is wrong), but it has no solution for $18 - i$. Indeed
$$
\begin{cases}
18 = a - 2b \\
-1 = 2a + b
\end{cases}
\quad \leftrightarrow \quad
\begin{cases}
2b = a - 18 \\
-2 = 4a + 2b
\end{cases}
\quad \leftrightarrow \quad
\begin{cases}
2b = a - 18 \\
5a = 16
\end{cases}
$$
has no solutions in $\Bbb{Z}^2$. Therefore $\gcd(11 + 7i,18 - i) = 1$.

Comment: So, if any $a$, $b$ in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, $(N(a),N(b)) \neq 1$ implies a, b are not relatively prime?

Comment: I want to know, suppose $2+i$ is g.c.d. then, $(11+7i)=(2+i)(5.8+0.6i)$. Is $(2+i)$ a factor of $(11+7i)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ ?

Comment: I'm saying that if $(a,b) = d$, then $(N(a),N(b)) = N(d)$, which allows you to restrict the possible choices for $d$. Right now I'm not sure about the converse implication, but I don't think that it is true.

Comment: It may be, but not like you wrote: $5.8 + 0.6i$ is not an element in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$!

Comment: but $(11+7i)=(2+i)(5.8+0.6i)$ right? So, if $(2+i)$ is the g.c.d. but $(2+i) \nmid (11+7i) in \mathbb{Z}[i] $ ?

Comment: The point is that for $2+i \mid 11+7i$ to hold in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ you must be able to write $(2+i)(a+ib) = 11+7i$ with $a,b \in \Bbb{Z}$...

Comment: @A.P. You might find it of interest that the divisibility can be tested quickly using the Lemma in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\,x = 11\!+\!7i,\,y = 18\!-\!i.\,$ Then $\,d\mid x,y\,\Rightarrow\,d\mid \overbrace{x\bar x}^{170},\overbrace{y\bar y}^{325}\,\Rightarrow\,d\mid(170,325)=5$

But neither prime factor of $\,5 = (2\!-\!i)(2\!+\!i)\,$ divides both $\,x,y\,$ since by the Lemma

$\qquad \  \begin{align}5&\,\nmid\ 18 - 1(2)\\ \Rightarrow\ i\!-\!2&\,\nmid\, 18 - 1\,(i)\end{align}\qquad $ and $\qquad\, \begin{align}5&\,\nmid\, 11 + 7(-2)\\ \Rightarrow\ i\!+\!2&\,\nmid\, 11 + 7\,( i)\end{align}$

**Lemma** $\ i\!-\!2\mid a\!+\!bi \iff 5\mid a\!+\!b(2)\,\ $ and $\,\ i\!+\!2\mid a\!+\!bi\iff 5\mid a\!+\!b(-2),\ $ because

$\ {\rm mod}\,\ \color{}{i\!-\!2}\!:\ \color{#c00}{i\equiv 2}\,\Rightarrow\, a\!+\!b\,\color{#c00}i\equiv a\!+\!b(\color{#c00}2),\ $ and $\ i\!-\!2\mid n\iff 5\mid n(i\!+\!2)\iff 5\mid n$

**Remark** $\ $ Generally we can use module normal forms (Hermite) to test ideal membership. By [this Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/608414/242) we know that the ideal $\,(i\!-\!2) = (5,i\!-\!2) = 5\,\Bbb Z + (i\!-\!2)\Bbb Z\,$ by $\,5\mid N(i\!-\!2),\ N = $ norm. Just as in linear algebra, it is easy to test membership when the subspace basis is triangularized. Here it amounts to modding out first by $\,i\!-\!2\,$ (i.e. replacing $\,i\,$ by $2)\,$ then modding out by $\,5.$

---

Alternatively we can use the Euclidean algorithm.

Note $\ d\mid 18\!-\!i,11\!+\!7i\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid 18\!-\!i-(11\!+\!7i) = 7\!-\!8i,$

thus $\ d\mid 11\!+\!7i-i(7\!-\!8i) = 3\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid 3(6)-(18\!-\!i) = i\,\Rightarrow d\mid i(-i) = 1$

**Remark** $\ $ Unwinding gives Bezout $\ (6-6i)(11+7i) + (i-6)(18-i) = 1$

Comment: @A.P. Please tell me what part you do not understand so I can elaborate.

Comment: Maybe I understand now. Do you mean that the class of $a+bi$ modulo $i-2$ is the same as the class of $a+2b$ and that $i-2$ divides an integer $n$ iff its norm does (which is clear, because $i-2 \mid n$ means $n \in (i-2)\Bbb{Z}[i] \cap \Bbb{Z}$)?

Comment: $\,\color{#c00}{i\!-\!2}\mid a\!+\!bi = a\!+\!b(2\!-\!2\!+\!i) = a\!+\!b(2)\!+\!b(\color{#c00}{i\!-\!2})\iff i\!-\!2\mid a\!+\!b(2).\,\ $ More generally $\,i\!-\!c\mid f(i)\iff i\!-\!c\mid f(c)\ $ for any polynomial $\,f\in\Bbb Z[x]\ $ by $\ i\equiv c\pmod{i\!-\!c}.\ $ $\tag*{}$
If $\,n\in\Bbb Z\,$ then by *rationalizing the denominator*

$$\dfrac{n}{2-i}\, =\, \dfrac{n}{2-i}\,\dfrac{2+i}{2+i}\, =\, \dfrac{2n}5 + \dfrac{n}5\, i\,\in\, \Bbb Z[i]\iff 5\mid n$$ @A.P. Clearer now? $\ \ $

Comment: Yes. That's what I said in my comment, although in different terms. ;)

Comment: @A.P. Right, but I thought an unwinding into more elementary terms might help other readers too (and I had already started writing it before your comment appeared).

Comment: @A.P. It's essentially a special case of testing ideal (as module) membership using Hermite normal forms - see the added remark and its link for references.