# How do I prove that $Z[w]/(a)\cong Z_{N(a)}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, quadratic-integer-rings

Define $S=\{\sqrt{D}:D\equiv 2,3 \pmod 4\}$

Define $T=\{\frac{1-\sqrt{D}}{2}:D\equiv 1 \pmod 4 \}$.

Let $w\in S\cup T$.

Let $N:\mathbb{Z}[w] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ be the norm.

Then how do I prove that $\mathbb{Z}[w]/(a)\cong \mathbb{Z}_{N(a)}$?

Answer (score 3):

The assertion is false: $\mathbb Z[\omega]/(a)$ may not be cyclic, for example $\mathbb Z[i]/(3)$ is not the cyclic group with $9$ elements, since it is the field with $9$ elements, whose additive group is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$.

Maybe you only want to show that $\mathbb Z[\omega]/(a)$ has $N(a)$ elements, which is true for any $a \in \mathbb Z[\omega]$.

Let me show this:

By the proof of the structure theorem of finitely generated abelian groups, we get a commutative diagram of exact sequences:

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
0@>>>\mathbb Z[\omega] @>\cdot a>> \mathbb Z[\omega] @>>> \mathbb Z[\omega]/(a) @>>> 0\\
& @VSVV @VTVV @VVV\\
0 @>>> \mathbb Z^2 @>M>> \mathbb Z^2 @>>> A @>>> 0 \\
\end{CD}

where $S$ and $T$ are matrices in $GL_2(\mathbb Z)$ and the isomorphism $\mathbb Z[\omega]/(a) \cong A$ is induced by abstract nonsense. $M$ can be chosen to be a diagonal matrix.

We conclude $|Z[\omega]/(a)|=|A| = |\mathbb Z^2/im(M)|$. We have $\mathbb Z^2/im(M)=\mathbb Z/k\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/l\mathbb Z$, where $k,l$ are the diagonal entries of $M$. So $|Z[\omega]/(a)|=|kl|=|\det M| = |\det (\cdot a)|$. The least equality holds because $S,T \in GL_2(\mathbb Z)$.

Showing $\det (\cdot a) = N(a)$ is an easy exercise, I gave you some hints in the comments.

Comment: How do I show that it has $N(a)$ elements?

Comment: By the proof (with presentations and smith normal form) of the structure theorem of finitely generated abelian groups, we deduce that the number of elements in $\mathbb Z[\omega]/(a)$ is precisely the absolute value of the determinant of the multiplication with $a$ on $\mathbb Z[\omega]$. This determinant can easily be checked to be the norm of $a$. This is trivial if we have $a \in \mathbb Z$. If we have $a \notin \mathbb Z$, note that we can compute the determinant after switchting to the quotient field. There you can use the basis $\{1,a\}$ to compute the determinant.

Comment: @Rubertos If this presentation is too abstract then [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/608414/242) for a more concrete way to proceed (see esp. the link to Franz Lemmermeyer's notes).